# evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u^r} E[\min(X,u^r)] du$

Tags: integration, expected-value

Trying to find the solution of $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u^r} E[\min(X,u^r)]\, du$$

$r>1$, $X>0$, $E[X^{\frac{1}{r}}] < \infty$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u^r} E[\min(X,u^r)] du &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u^r} \int_0^{u^r}P(X>s) ds du \\
\text{integrating by parts} \quad  &= \int_0^{u^r}P(X>s)ds \frac{u^{-r+1}}{-r+1}|_{u=0}^\infty -\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{-r+1}}{-r+1}P(X > u^r) du\\
\text{letting } t = u^r\quad &= \frac{r}{r-1}\int_0^\infty P(X > t) dt = \frac{r}{r-1} E[X]
\end{aligned}
$$

The solution shouljd be $\frac{r}{r-1} E[X^{\frac{1}{r}}]$ but I can't see where I'm going wrong. Anything will help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the second line. I would substitute $t=u^r$ in the first line and apply Fubini, yielding $\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\frac{1}{r}-1}}{rt}\int_0^tP(X>s)dsdt=\int_0^\infty P(X>s)\int_s^\infty\frac{1}{r}t^{\frac{1}{r}-2}dtds=\int_0^\infty P(X>s)\frac{1}{r-1}s^{\frac{1}{r}-1}ds$. Substitute $t=s^{1/r}$, then this yields $\int_0^\infty P(X>s)\frac{1}{r-1}t^{1-r}rt^{r-1}dt$.